# Plotting a plane using intercepts

Tags: plotting

I have a plane `2x + 5y + z = 10`. I have determined that its intercepts are:

```
x = 5, y = 2, z = 10
```

I need to use `Plot3D` specifically to plot the plane formed by these three points. How might I go about doing that?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Read the [faq]!
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge.
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ContourPlot3D[2 x + 5 y + z == 10, {x, 0, 6}, {y, 0, 3}, {z, 0, 11}, Mesh -> None]
```

[image]

or

```
Graphics3D[Polygon[{{5, 0, 0}, {0, 2, 0}, {0, 0, 10}}],  BoxRatios -> 1, Axes -> True]
```

[image]

or

```
Plot3D[ Piecewise[{{10 - 2 x - 5 y, 10 - 2 x - 5 y >= 0}}, 
  Indeterminate], {x, 0, 6}, {y, 0, 3}, Mesh -> None, BoxRatios -> 1]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can use

```
InfinitePlane[{{5, 0, 0}, {0, 2, 0}, {0, 0, 10}}]
```

The plane will extend throughout the plot range:

```
Graphics3D[{
  InfinitePlane[{{5, 0, 0}, {0, 2, 0}, {0, 0, 10}}]
  },
 PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, {0, 10}, {0, 10}},
 Axes -> True]]
```

and

```
Graphics3D[{
  InfinitePlane[{{5, 0, 0}, {0, 2, 0}, {0, 0, 10}}]
  },
 PlotRange -> 10,
 Axes -> True]
```

preoduce, respectively,

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 1):

```
Plot3D[10 - 2 x - 5 y, {x, 0, 6}, {y, 0, 3}, 
 RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, 0 < x && 0 < y && 0 < z], 
 Axes -> True, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}, Boxed -> False]
```

for view:

```
points = {{5, 0, 0}, {0, 2, 0}, {0, 0, 10}};
    Show[Graphics3D[{Blue, Sphere[points, .2]}, Axes -> True, 
      Boxed -> False, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}, 
      AxesStyle -> Directive[{Thick, Black}]], 
     Plot3D[10 - 2 x - 5 y, {x, 0, 6}, {y, 0, 3}, 
      RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, 0 < x && 0 < y && 0 < z], 
      Mesh -> None]]
```

[image]